# How to avoid copying temp instance of a class by return by reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, deep-copy, return-by-reference

I am new to c++ and got really confused about this class of numerical array I am trying to implement. I hope somebody can give me some advice:

```
class ndarray {
public:
double *data;
...
ndarray(...) { \* code to dynamically allocate data *\}
ndarray(const ndarray& A) { \* code to copy construct *\}
~ndarray() { \* code to delete data *\};

ndarray& operator=(const ndarray& A) {\* code to deep copy *\}

friend ndarray& log(const ndarray& A) { 
    ndarray B(...); 
    \* code to popularize B[i] with log(A[i])  *\
    return B; }
};
int main() {
    ndarray A(...), B(...);
    B=log(A);
}
```

Here I overloaded the `=` operator to deep copy the data elements. After inserting some outputs to the code I found that the `B=log(A)` code has called the `=` operator explicitly by creating and popularizing a new data array elementwise, even though the overloaded `log` function returns by reference. My question is, how can I avoid this extra copying of data elementwise and use the `ndarray` object created by `log` function directly. Obviously the compiler is not helping me in this case.

Comment: Returning a reference to a local variable is broken (a good compiler will print a warning). I think you want to read up on return value optimization and rvalue references (aka move semantics). Also, std::valarray might fit your needs (it uses a more complicated expression template mechanism to reduce copying).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the return by reference a local variable issue. Somehow the compiler (visual c++ 2012) did not complain. The code runs as if it returns by value. The question remains on how to avoid copy of the returned value element-wise. If I overload the ``=`` operator without deep copy, my code crashes at the end when these objects are being destructed. That I don't understand, since the ``log(A)`` call created the array and assigned the pointer only to ``B.data``. Upon destruction, why should it crash? Also the ``std::valarray`` class seems obsolete.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A hasty decision, because the question of "how can I avoid this extra copying of data elementwise and use the ndarray object created by log function directly." is not answered by the linked.

Comment: @user138668 _"The question remains on how to avoid copy of the returned value element-wise."_ Use an output parameter passed by reference.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Vote to reopen the question, if you think the decision was wrong.

Comment: @user138668 - "how can I avoid this extra copying of data elementwise" Answer: in C++0x and , you need to look for ['move constructible/assignable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's a duplicate all-right - except that the linked by itself doesn't answer to his question of "How to avoid copying".

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I now more or less understand, that I need to dig into the "move constructor" and "move assignment" concepts.